# How to subtract two separate columns in a file

Tags: python, linux

I have a file that looks like this:

```
scaf12446   275     482     loc.04759  .       +       9.99087136654
scaf9003    58436   58745   loc.36424  .       +       9.98867551051e-07
scaf6164    41519   44781   loc.29229  .       -       9.97790659076e-07
scaf20      64796   100635  loc.14273  .       -       9.97726500173
scaf19280   12335   12568   loc.13668  .       +       9.95702976886
scaf8877    30882   32362   loc.36113  .       -       9.94423702955e-08
```

I want to subtract the 3rd column from the 2nd column and print out the values. So the resultant file should be like this:

```
scaf12446   207     loc.04759  .       +       9.99087136654
    scaf9003    309   loc.36424  .       +       9.98867551051e-07
    scaf6164    3262   loc.29229  .       -       9.97790659076e-07
    scaf20      35839  loc.14273  .       -       9.97726500173
    scaf19280   233   loc.13668  .       +       9.95702976886
    scaf8877    1480  loc.36113  .       -       9.94423702955e-
```

This table is quite long - would there be an easy way to simply subtract column 3 from column 2? A linux shortcut would be ideal.

Comment: What's the delimiter?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python and pandas

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

"""
sub_col.py

Call as
    $ python sub_col.py file
"""

import sys
import pandas as pd

def main(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    df[2] -= df[1]
    del df[1]
    df.to_csv(file, header=False, index=False, sep='\t')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Output dataframe:

```
scaf12446   207 loc.04759   .   +   9.990871366539999
scaf9003    309 loc.36424   .   +   9.98867551051e-07
scaf6164    3262    loc.29229   .   -   9.97790659076e-07
scaf20  35839   loc.14273   .   -   9.97726500173
scaf19280   233 loc.13668   .   +   9.95702976886
scaf8877    1480    loc.36113   .   -   9.944237029550001e-08
```